# Using capital gains to start a business?

Tags: united-states, taxes, real-estate, capital-gains-tax, small-business

Lets say I make 100k profit in selling some stocks. Can I use that 100k to start a Business without paying Capitol gains? The Business would be used to buy and sell properties. Maybe a bar.

Answer (score 5):

No.

Purchasing (specific types) of real estate with the proceeds of the sale of (that same type of) real estate is the only way to not pay capital gains on otherwise taxable property.